# Is it possible for a times series to not have any residual component after additive/multiplicative decomposition?

Tags: python, time-series

After conducting a times series additive decomposition using [statmodels](https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/generated/statsmodels.tsa.seasonal.seasonal_decompose.html), the chart shows only a trend component, and there isn't any seasonal or residual component observed. [image]

I was wondering how credible the results would be if I continue the analysis with such results, and also would like to know what may cause such patterns in the series. Thanks.